# C++ Set Array In Pointer to Struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a struct in C++ as follows:

```
typedef struct DIFDict
{
    std::string name;
    std::string defs[];
    struct DIFColor *colors[];
    uint8_t defsize; 
} DIFDict;
```

The trouble is trying to initialize it. I have a function which returns a pointer to a struct with all the values initialized:

```
struct DIFDict *CreateDIFDict(std::string n, std::string *d, struct DIFColor **c, uint8_t de)
{
    int memsize = sizeof(n) + sizeof(d) + sizeof(c) + sizeof(de);
    struct DIFDict *i = static_cast<struct DIFDict*>(malloc(memsize));

    if(i != NULL)
    {
        i->name = n;
        i->defs = d;
        i->colors = c;
        i->defsize = de;
    }

    return i;

}
```

However, the compiler complains of type mismatches:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'std::string [0] {aka std::basic_string<char> [0]}'
error: incompatible types in assignment of 'DIFColor**' to 'DIFColor* [0]'
```

Am I misunderstanding the relationship between pointers and arrays?

Comment: Don't mix C with C++. call malloc for string will not construct the string object.

Comment: `malloc()` doesn't call default constructors. Use `new` instead.

Comment: This struct definition is illegal in both C and C++.  C++ does not permit `[]` anywhere in the struct definition; and C only permits it as the final member of a struct. (notwithstanding the fact that `std::string` does not exist in C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef struct DIFDict
{
    std::string name;
    std::string *defs;
    struct DIFColor **colors;
    uint8_t defsize; 
} DIFDict;

struct DIFDict *CreateDIFDict(std::string n, std::string *d, struct DIFColor *c, uint8_t de)
{   
    DIFDict *i = 0;
    i = new DIFDict;

    if(i != 0)
    {
        i->name = n;
        i->defs = d;
        i->colors = &c;
        i->defsize = de;

        return i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: The issue with the answer above is that the `DIFColor` parameter is a temporary, and pointer to the temporary will be invalid when the function exits.  A more viable (not the best, but at least viable) solution that closely mimics the above would be as follows:

```
    struct DIFDict
    {
        std::string name;
        std::string *defs;
        DIFColor **colors;
        uint8_t defsize; 
    };

    DIFDict *CreateDIFDict(const std::string& n, std::string *d, 
                           DIFColor **c, uint8_t de) 
    {   
        DIFDict *i = new DIFDict;
        i->name = n;
        i->defs = d;
        i->colors = c;
        i->defsize = de;
        return i;
    }
```

Note that we do not now take the address of the temporary -- all we're passing the  pointer value directly and having it assigned.  Also, note that `new` does not return 0 on failure (unless the `nothrow` option is used), so no check is needed for `new` being 0.

However, this solution is still C-like and is error-prone, and there are much better methods, as outlined by the other answers given.

Comment: `c` is an automatic variable, so `i->colors` is a wild pointer as soon as this function returns

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have some basic misunderstanding of arrays in C++. They have have a fixed size, known at compile-time. Zero-sized arrays are illegal. (Some compilers allow a zero-sized array when not invoked in standard mode, however they have unclear semantics, and certainly can't have any value stored in them).

Also you use `sizeof` wrongly. `sizeof x` tells you how many bytes are required to store `x`. (NOT anything that `x` may be pointing to, if `x` is a pointer, and not anything that `x` is a handle for, or a container class of).  For example `std::string` is a container which has a pointer pointing to dynamically-allocated string contents. `sizeof name` only gets you the container size, it does not get you how much space has been dynamically allocated.

In your code, `memsize` can be determined at compile-time; it would never be different on different calls to the function.

Further, using a function `CreateDIFDict` is poor style as it forces dynamic allocation. Instead, provide a constructor. Then the user can choose whether they want dynamic allocation, and they can take advantage of move and copy semantics.

It's not clear whether or not you want `DIFDict` to take a copy of the strings and DIFColors that you are initializing it with. If you do not want a copy:

```
struct DIFDict
{
    std::string name;
    std::string *defs;
    struct DIFColor **colors;
    uint8_t defsize; 

    DIFDict(std::string name, std::string *defs, struct DIFColor **colors, uint8_t defsize) :
         name(name), defs(defs), colors(colors), defsize(defsize) {}
};
```

Make very sure that you destroy all `DIFDict`s before you destroy the things that the pointers are pointing to. (Raw pointers do not have an ownership semantic in C++).

If you do want a copy:

```
struct DIFDict
{ 
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> defs;    // or some other container
    // ??? colors

    DIFDict(std::string name, std::string const *p_defs, uint8_t defsize)
         : name(name), defs(p_defs, p_defs + defsize) {}
};
```

I'm not sure what `colors` is supposed to point to, if you give more information about the expected behaviour of colors I'll update this example.

Answer (score 1):

This is C++, not C. Drop the typedef and initialize it as you would a class. The only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is default visibility of the members. Something like:

```
struct DIFDict
{
    string name;
    vector<string> defs;
    DIFColor* colors;
    uint8_t defsize; 

    DIFDict();
    ~DIFDict();    
};

DIFDict::DIFDict : name(""), defs(...), colors(...), defsize(0) {}
DIFDict::~DIFDict() {...}
```

And as  0x499602D2 points out below, you should probably use a `vector` for your arrays.

The ellipses mean to create a helper to initialize the members. The helper should ensure the constructor behaves as expected during an exception.

Comment: Completely irrelevant.

Comment: Don't even need the second `struct` and that array of pointers can be changed into a `std::vector` or `std::array` of `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Blindy - forgive my ignorance, but how is it irrelevant? The question is labeled C++, and he's trying to initialize his struct: *"... the trouble is trying to initialize it"*. What would you use?

Comment: `This is C++` Zero-size arrays are non-standard.

Comment: I'm actually thinking about using a map now, since each def would match a color

Comment: @jww even if zero-sized arrays were legal, how would `{0}` be a valid initializer for one? What memory gets set to what by this initialization?

Comment: @Matt - yes, you're right. I glossed over that. Its been removed. I attempted to steer him to C++, struct and construction.